# OSB java callout function - Cast XmlAnyTypeImpl to String

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oracle11g, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am trying to create a java call out function in OSB(version 11.1.3) to decode the URL. I can use `java.net.URLDecoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");` in the program, but OSB function gives below error(When input and return type are String)

```
<Jun 11, 2014 7:43:30 AM UTC> <Error> <OSB Transform> <BEA-382516> <Failed to evaluate expression for callout to java method "public static java.lang.String com.help.sachinProject.ttttt.test(java.lang.String)". Argument index: 1, exception: Value of type 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl' cannot be type-cast to 'java.lang.String'>
<Jun 11, 2014 7:43:35 AM UTC> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.232.24.59:49,359 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
```

So I should both input and return type as **XmlAnyTypeImpl** . How do I convert String to  XmlAnyTypeImpl *(XmlAnyTypeImpl available in xmlbeans.jar)* ?

Here is my new program

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl;
public class XMLFormatDecode {

XMLFormatDecode(){
super();
}

   public static String getValue(XmlAnyTypeImpl data)    
       {
       String decoded = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(data.toString(), "UTF-8");
       return decoded;                                         
       }


public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
new XMLFormatDecode();
System.out.println("Result main - "+XMLFormatDecode.getValue(null));
       }
}
```

**will XmlAnyTypeImpl.toString() works ?**

**Can someone help me to convert String to XmlAnyTypeImpl ?**

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring because it can't pass `XmlAnyType` **TO** your static java method.  You aren't specifying what you pass to the Java method, so I can only assume you aren't casting it properly to the right type.  It gets an `XmlAnyTypeImpl` which needs to be converted to something else (String, int, boolean, etc.).  You can probably just tweak what you're passing to the Java callout using some form of the XS Constructors:

[image: XS Constructors]

[image: Java Callout]

Comment: Can you just look at the error? This occurred when I pass String and returned String.

Comment: We have used XS Constructors: in OSB console, but still getting same error.

Comment: Now gettting <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.232.24.59:61,669 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs>
<Jun 16, 2014 11:49:34 AM UTC> <Error> <OSB Transform> <BEA-382516> <Failed to evaluate expression for callout to java method "public static java.lang.String com.osb.java.callout.XMLFormatDecode.getValue(org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl)". Argument index: 1, exception: Value of type 'com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.EndpointTypeImpl' cannot be type-cast to 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlAnyTypeImpl'>

Comment: If you look at [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15867/proxy_actions.htm#i1321171), Java methods can only be a small subset of types, and `XmlAnyTypeImpl` isn't one of them.  Going back to my original answer, are you actually getting the text() out of a node (e.g. `$body/node/node/text()`), or just blindly passing xs:string() to some node hoping to have it convert your stuff into the right thing?

Comment: Dear Nick,In OSB we have case that we should pass a URL to outbound,but the URL is encoded with java.net.Encode,So I tried Decodng with java.net.Decode with java callout.So I creatd a pgm with both input&return type r String then got the error(mentiond in the queston-line 4).By looking at the error I came to know that input should be in the format of XmlAnyTypeImpl.So My program changed(mentioned in the question)with XmlAnyTypeImpl input.Now I am getting  "Value of type com.bea.wli.sb.context.impl.EndpointTypeImpl' cannot type-cast to .XmlAnyTypeImpl'".Pasing URL hoping it converts with method

Comment: When I pass to OSB outbound - <con:reason>Failed to set the value of context variable "outbound". Value must be an instance of {http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context}endpoint.</con:reason>